# Inverse functions and derivatives

Tags: analysis

Suppose $f: A \to B$ is bijective, and suppose f is differentiable at $a \in A$, assume $f^{-1}$ is differentiable.

prove $(f^{-1})'(f(a)) = \dfrac{1}{f'(a)}$

we done this lecture and the proof my lecture wrote is as follows,

$f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$ so $ 1 =  \dfrac{d}{dx} x \displaystyle  |_{x=a}  = (f^{-1})'(f(a))\times f'(a)$ I don't understand it from here - how does $ 1 =(f^{-1})'(f(a))\times f'(a)$, where did he get $f'(a)$ from, and shouldn't it just be 1 = $(f^{-1})'(f(a))$

Comment: Chain rule. $$(g\circ f)'(x) = g'(f(x))\cdot f'(x).$$

Comment: You further need that $f'(a)\neq 0$.

Comment: @GitGud That holds by the assumption that $f^{-1}$ is diff'able, doesnt it?

Comment: @user127001 I suspect you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Try chain rule on $f^{-1}\circ f.$

**ADD**:  You may calculate the derivative of both sides of the equality $f^{-1}\circ f(x)=x$.

to do this, use chain rule for the left side of the equality (I mean $f^{-1}(f(x))$  ).